# I have a question is watching youtube haram

Tags: halal-haram

when you watch youtube sometimes it shows inappropriate videos and I think it's haram to watch youtube

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays, western culture is everywhere.
Many, many videos contain women who aren’t properly dressed, music, swearing, etc.

If you’re a strict Muslim, the best I can offer is yes UNLESS it’s only for the sake of watching Islamic lectures/listening to Quran recitation because these videos don’t really contain music or nudity/haram.

I would say video tutorials also wouldn’t be haram, though if you’re a male, you would have to watch videos made by other men and vice versa. If they have music you could mute the video, or you could just Google tutorials instead of watching videos.

So as long as you stay in the boundaries of what is halal, it doesn’t necessarily have to be haram.
And not every video contains women/music, but just weary and cautious.

Comment: I am actually not a strict muslim

Comment: @user44422 then be weary of what you come across on YouTube. Don’t cross the boundaries that would make YouTube haram. Don’t watch videos with women unnecessarily (if you’re a male) and vice versa.

Comment: thanks for the comment but how do you know that is true

Comment: @user44422 Muslim men are told to lower their gaze? I’m not sure I follow what you mean. If men can’t look at women, what makes it okay for men to casually stare at women in videos? Not to mention women don’t cover their body on YouTube.

Comment: emm ok by the way thanks for answer I really appreciated it